# How to remove the dot?

Tags: java

I started to study JAVA, So sorry for the question.. I practice the WHILE LOOP, so I have this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Class {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println( "Type in a message" );
        System.out.print( "Message: " );
        String message = keyboard.nextLine();

        double n = 0;
        while ( n < 10 )
        {
            System.out.println( (n+1) + "." +  message );
            n++;
        }

    }
}
```

so, I want to get a result somthing like that: 10. 20. 30. and etc..

but I get: 1.0. , 2.0., 3.0. and etc..

what I should do to remove this dot, between 1 and 0...? thank you very much for your help :).

Comment: Why would you expect to get 10, 20, ...? You are incrementing n by 1

Comment: I need to get 10 20 30 and etc and not 1 2 3.. what I should do?

Comment: so, I need to remove the dot..

Comment: Either do `n += 10` or as @Aominè suggested in he answer

Comment: @ein what dot? between `n` and `message`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a quick fix to your problem would be first changing the data type to int, so `int n = 0;` then simply add `"0."` to your print statement, so it looks like:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println( "Type in a message" );
 System.out.print( "Message: " );
 String message = keyboard.nextLine();

  int n = 0;
  while ( n < 10 ) {
    System.out.println( (n+1) + "0." +  message );
    n++;
  }
 }
}
```

Or, alternatively, you could do `int n = 10` and have your while loop condition as`while( n < 100 )` then increment `n` by ten (`n+=10;`). So now it would look like:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println( "Type in a message" );
 System.out.print( "Message: " );
 String message = keyboard.nextLine();

  int n = 10;
  while ( n < 100 ) {
    System.out.println(n + "." +  message);
    n+=10;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very help me :)

Comment: No problem, ein!

Answer (score 3):

Use `int` instead of `double` for `n` variable:

```
int n = 0;
```

Comment: I need to get 10.  20.   30. 40.  but int i get 1. 2. 3.  what i should do?

Comment: @ein see the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can increment in 10s by multiplying `n` by `10`, Also you might want to use `int` type rather than `double` to remove the decimal point.

```
int n = 1;
while ( n <= 10 )
{
    System.out.println( (  10 * n) "." +  message );
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's now work :) , you help me very much !!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
int n = 10; // start from 10 and change it from double to int to get rid of decimal point
while ( n <= 100 ){
    System.out.println(  n + "." +  "message");
    n+=10; // increment by 10 after every loop
}
```